# Find the moment of inertia about $x$-axis of the region bounded by $y=x^2$ and $y=x$

Tags: integration

Find the moment of inertia about $x$-axis of the region bounded by $y=x^2$ and $y=x$, if the density is proportional to the distance from the $x$-axis. And the answer should represented by the mass of the region.

I tried first let the density 
$$\rho=ky$$
Then the moment of inertia is
$$\int^1_0\int^x_{x^2}y^2\cdot ky \ dy dx=\frac{k}{45}$$
Then calculate the mass of the region as 
$$M=\int^1_0\int^x_{x^2}ky \ dydx=\frac{k}{15}$$
So the moment of inertia is $$\frac{M}{3}$$
But the answer is $$\frac{M}{8}$$
There is no detailed solution so I don't know where I got wrong...

Comment: I just checked and it looks like your answer is right. The textbook must have gotten it wrong. :)

Comment: @TristanBatchler Thank you for checking~

Comment: For what it's worth, I also agree with your answer. I even tried doing the problem for the solid of revolution of that area around the $x$ axis, but it still is not even close to $M/8$.